# Openshift oc login unable to login

Tags: openshift

I am trying to use `oc login https://server:6443` to login to openshift. However I get the error

```
error: Seems you passed an HTML page (console?) instead of server URL.
Verify provided address and try again.
```

Even when I try going to into console and copy login command with the token login, I still get the error. My co worker can login no problem with either of the commands. I just joined the company and nobody seems to know what is causing the issue.

Comment: What happens if you `curl https://server:6443` ?

Answer (score 1):

from any of your openshift node try to run below command and pass your username/password.

**oc login -u username**